# Shortening file name in one column and writing to new column using dplyr

Tags: dplyr, rename

So I have a large data set with very long original file names (and many rows [~15,000-25,000]). I can do this easily if less efficiently in Excel, but i'd ideally like to keep all modifications to the spreadsheet contained in R for reproducibility. For graphing purposes i'd like to shorten these names to fit nicely on a graph (there is 28-56). The file names are in a column calling idFile. I have created a second column called Short-file-name. Based on "idFile", I'd like to shorten to the middle section "**********exp_057_A*******" and then everywhere this appears, have "Sample_0057_A" write to column "Short-file-name". Ideally, I'd like to do this using dplyr and R since the next steps will be creating a "condition" column whereby everywhere A is found, this writes "Condition A" to this row and so on (which i think falls under pattern mapping). However, I am a bit stuck and don't know where to really start. Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Comment: Can you provide an example? You would like to change the name of files or name of data frame in R, or something else? This sounds similar to what vlookup will lead you to (or _join_ in dplyr), but I'd like to get a better understanding.

Comment: No problem. So ideally, this is simplified (given this has to try and loop through the 25,000 rows)   idFile=c("2020_08_09_spp_exp_001_A.mzid",
         "2020_08_09_spp_exp_006_A.mzid",
         "2020_08_09_spp_exp_002_A.mzid",
         "2020_08_09_spp_exp_005_A.mzid",
         "2020_08_09_spp_exp_003_A.mzid")
         
Short_file_name=c("Sample-1",
                  "Sample-6",
                 "Sample-2",
                  "Sample-5",
                  "Sample-3")

test_Data=cbind(idFile,Short_file_name) (what i want is the second column). Then following up with the condition col

Comment: Ok, so this worked, but i wonder can i shorten it? `AF.df2=AF.df %>%
  mutate(Short.id=case_when(grepl("spp_exp_001_A",idFile) ~ "Sample-1",
                            grepl("spp_exp_006_A",idFile) ~ "Sample-6",
                            grepl("spp_exp_004_A",idFile) ~ "Sample-4"))  %>%
  mutate(Condition=case_when(grepl("spp_exp_001_A",idFile) ~ "Neg-ctrl",
                             grepl("spp_exp_002_A",idFile) ~ "Neg-ctrl",
                             grepl("spp_exp_006_A",idFile) ~ "Pos-ctrl"))`